# Is there a lisp cdr equivalence for c++ std::list

Tags: c++, lisp, cdr

Some people have their custom list class with `car`(eg. head) `cdr`(eg. tail).  I'm wondering if `std::list` can be used to support these operations.  `car` is trivial.  But I don't know how `cdr` can be emulated.

Comment: If you want to modify the list in place, then `pop_front`. If you want to make a copy of the tail portion, then `std::list<SomeType>{std::next(mylist.begin()), mylist.end()};`

Comment: C++ lists don't expose their structure, which is what you would need for "proper" Lisp lists (Newell-Shaw-Simon lists).

Comment: @IgorTandetnik But `pop_front` lose the orignal list?  With lisp `cdr`, the orignal list is still available.

Comment: Have you read the second part of my comment?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: making a copy of the tail is not what `cdr` does.

Comment: @tfb maybe by providing a custom allocator it could be possible to share structure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++20, we're getting the Ranges library. I haven't looked at it in much detail yet, but I suspect that subranges or views might help here.

### Pre C++20

In C++ (up until now), we often don't directly pass a list (or other container) around, but rather a pair of iterators. Take a look at the `<algorithm>` library: functions like `std::sort` don't take a reference to a container - instead, they take a `first` iterator and an `last` iterator.

Important: `last` does *not* point to the last item, but rather one place beyond it - the same as `std::list::end()` would give you. This means that when `first == last` you have "an empty list"

In a pre-C++20 world, you would generally write your code in the same way. One of the advantages of doing this is that if you have a pair of iterators `first` and `last`, then (as long as  `first != last`) `*first` is the `car`, and the pair `std::next(first)` and `last` is the `cdr`. So:

```lisp
(defun sum (list)
  (if (null list)
      0
    (+ (car list) (sum (cdr list)))))
```

becomes something like

```cpp
template <class ForwardIter>
int sum(ForwardIter first, ForwardIter last) {
  return (first == last)
           ? 0
           : (*first) + sum(std::next(first), last);
}
```

(I know some people would disagree with how I've formatted that conditional operator over multiple lines - but I wanted to mirror the Lisp style.)